# How to use qsort for string in C++

Tags: c++, qsort

I want to use qsort function to sort the characters in the strings using C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int compare_str(void const *a,void const *b){
    char const *aa=(char const *)a;
    char const *bb=(char const *)b;

    if(*aa==*bb) return 0;
    else if(*aa>*bb) return 1;
    else return -1;
}
int main(){

    string str="cake";
    int len=str.length();

    qsort(str,len,sizeof(str[0]),compare_str);
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

But it throws :

```
20 42 [Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'void*' for argument '1' to 'void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*, const void*))'
```

It would be great if anyone could provide an efficient way to do this.

Comment: You know `std::sort` exists right?

Comment: `std::sort` uses algorithms like mergesort or quicksort, which are inefficient for sorting sequences like a `string`. Consider alternatives like `radix sort`, which are asymptotically optimal in the general case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I strongly recommend the modern method of

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("cake");

    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());

    std::cout << s << std::endl; // Prints "acek".

    return 0;
}
```

Plus, using `std::sort` over `qsort` allows the compiler to optimize better, so it's a win-win...

Answer (score 4):

Your comparator for `qsort` expects C strings, not C++ `std::string`s. You should either declare `str` to be `char str[]`

```
char str[] = "cake";
qsort(str, strlen(cake), sizeof(char), compare_str); // Consider renaming to compare_char
```

or (better) use `std::sort`:

```
string str = "cake";
sort(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: Your example with `vector<string> str` will sort the strings in the vector, not the individual characters in the strings, correct?  It's a little unclear whether he is just sorting one string or many...

Comment: @RyanMcK Ah, you're right, it looks like the OP wants to sort individual characters!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -- As you know `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.  Further, the number of characters in `str` is not 3.  Better to write your call to `qsort` as `qsort(str, strlen(str), 1, compare_char)` YMMV.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Right, 3 was there from my prior edit - I put `strlen` back. Keeping sizeof in is OK with me for descriptiveness. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, just pass a pointer to the string's contents:

```
qsort(str.c_str(),len,sizeof(str[0]),compare_str);
```

That said, you really should consider using the functions provided in the STL rather than those from the old C library...

Comment: s/STL/Standard Library/

Comment: If you're going to go that route, probably better to use str.c_str(). But as many others have said, std::sort is the best choice.

Comment: Never mind, asker wanted to sort the string in place. My mistake. Nevertheless, is &str[0] guaranteed to work?

Comment: @Joel -- `c_str()` returns a pointer to `const char`.  Passing it to `qsort` is UB.

Comment: Yeah, realized my mistake shortly after saying that. Main thing I was getting at is whether the &str[0] would work, though I suppose given that the code is using str.length() rather than strlen(&str[0]) it should be ok.

Comment: Come to think of it, the bytes may not be guaranteed to be null terminated without calling std::string::c_str(). Thanks for raising the point, Joel.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function sort() under the header `<algorithm>`. This function is very flexible and you can use it in different manner. For sorting as you wish in question you can just write:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s="cake";

sort(s.begin(), s.end());

cout << s << endl;

return 0;
}

//output: acek
```

again by using sort() we can implement it in a range. If you want to sort first two element , the code will be

```
sort(s.begin(), s.begin()+2);
```

for above code the output will be

```
//output: acke
```

so if we want to sort first `n` element then we can write

```
sort(s.begin,s.begin()+n);
```

we can also modify the sort function. In that case we have to pass three parameter instead of two. The third parameter will be a functions which returns a `bool` value.For example , if we want to sort in descending order then our code will be like this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool desc(char i, char j)
{
    return i>j;
}

int main()
{
    string s="cake";

    sort(s.begin(), s.end(),desc);

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}

//output: keca
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int compare_str(void const *a,void const *b){
    char const *aa=(char const *)a;
    char const *bb=(char const *)b;

    if(*aa==*bb) return 0;
    else if(*aa>*bb) return 1;
    else return -1;
}
int main(){

    string str="cake";
    int len=str.length();

    qsort(const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()),len,sizeof(str[0]),compare_str);
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```