# Compare function for qsort using two fields of a structure?

Tags: c, structure, qsort

Let's suppose we have a structure:

```
     struct product 
 {
    char name[30]; 
    float price;
 };
```

I want to sort it using qsort first by price, and if the prices are equal, by name. How I thought of writing the compare function:

```
    int compare(const void *a, const void *b )
{
    int comp =  a.price - b.price;

    if (comp < 0 )
    return 1
    if (comp > 0 )
        return 0;


    comp = strcmp(a.name, b.name);

   if ( comp  < 0 )
       return 1;
   else
   if ( comp > 0 ) 
       return 0;

}
```

Since I have only used the usual compare function for qsort, I don't know how to go about this. I think that I'm accessing the fields incorrectly, based on the errors given, so could you please point out my mistakes writing the compare function?

Comment: this is C, not C++... and you have several syntax errors in your code, I suggest you to read it carefully and look for these by yourself, or you will never progress

Comment: If you're using C++, don't use `qsort`, use `std::sort` instead (and use `std::string`). If you're using C, please edit your question and check other examples of qsort usage. Also turn on your compiler warnings to the max once you've fixed the type problems.

Comment: the mysterious "errors given"

Comment: Okay, I managed to use std::sort successfully. Also, the errors were related to accessing the structure's fields: a.price gave me a " 'a' does not have class type" error, if I well remember. I was not aware that std::sort is the way to go in C++, since I only recently switched from C. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use qsort for string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758055/how-to-use-qsort-for-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written has several syntax errors, and also your comparison function doesn't do quite what you want.  Quoting from the manpage for `qsort`:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>          greater  than  zero  if the first argument is considered to be respec‐
>          tively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.  If  two  mem‐
>          bers compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct product {
    char name[30]; 
    float price;
};

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {

  const struct product *x = a;   // void* can be assigned to any other pointer type
  const struct product *y = b;

  int comp =  x->price - y->price;

  if (comp < 0)
    return -1;

  if (comp > 0)
    return 1;

  comp = strcmp(x->name, y->name);

  return comp;
}
```

If you want to reverse the sort order, negate `comp` at the appropriate place.

As others have mentioned, this is C code, and is not idiomatic C++.

Comment: Note: `void*` CANNOT be assigned to any other pointer in C++.

Comment: Question is not tagged `C++`, so the comment above this one is completely off-topic, and  your edit to the end of your post is superfluous.  (As so many on this site point out, `C` and `C++` are two different languages.