# Qsort and strcmp

Tags: c

I am having trouble with this code, beacuse it won't compile properly. I am getting this mistake:

> initializing 'loebsdata2017' (aka 'struct loebsdata2017')
>         with an expression of incompatible type 'loebsdata2017 *' (aka 'struct
>         loebsdata2017 *'); dereference with *

And I don't know what to change in my code.

```
int sammenlign_hold (const void *p1, const void *p2);
void opgave_2 (loebsdata2017 *alle_loebsdata2017) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PERSONER; i++) {
        qsort (alle_loebsdata2017, 792, sizeof (loebsdata2017), sammenlign_hold);
        if(strcmp(alle_loebsdata2017[i].nationalitet, "DEN") == 0) 
        {

            printf("%s    \n", alle_loebsdata2017[i].rytternavn);
        }
    }
}

int sammenlign_hold (const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    loebsdata2017 resultat1 = (loebsdata2017 *)p1,
    loebsdata2017 resultat2 = (loebsdata2017 *)p2;

    return strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterhold, resultat2 -> rytterhold)
}
```

Comment: When you ask question about build errors, then please copy (as text) the complete output and paste it (without modifications) into the question body. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then *edit your question* to improve it.

Comment: As a hint though, with `(loebsdata2017 *)p1` you cast `p1` as a *pointer* to a `loebsdata2017` object, and then you assign this *pointer* to the variable `resultat1` which is *not* a pointer. Does that seem correct?

Comment: In your example, it should be sufficient to sort the data once, before the loop instead of once for every loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten the  `*` in  the pointer declaration:

```
int sammenlign_hold (const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    loebsdata2017 *resultat1 = (loebsdata2017 *)p1;
    loebsdata2017 *resultat2 = (loebsdata2017 *)p2;

    return strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterhold, resultat2 -> rytterhold)
}
```

Comment: Do I need to put semicolon ";" after

 loebsdata2017 *resultat1 = (loebsdata2017 *)p1,

instead of ","?

Comment: Yes, or `loebsdata2017 *resultat1 = (loebsdata2017 *)p1,
     *resultat2 = (loebsdata2017 *)p2;`  (I've updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am also trying to sort my data alphabetically, but I can't seem to figure out how. Is there a prototype for how it is done?

Comment: @RachelHutchings Isn't that what you're doing? Comparing strings in `qsort()` generally leads to an alphabetic sort. This is hard since your structure is not shown, and the field names are not in English.

Comment: @RachelHutchings Your current sorting function sorts on `rytterhold`. To sort on more than one field, you need to expand your sorting function a bit. You can find an example here (the example sorts on int and string, but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it for two string fields): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732011/compare-function-for-qsort-using-two-fields-of-a-structure